# How to find the kernel source files for a given version of fedora 29, for eg: 4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64?

Tags: linux, fedora-29

I would like to analyse the kernel drivers for a given version (uname -a) of fedora-29 distro: for eg: 4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64. How to get the appropriate version of source files, patches etc? To rephrase the same, can we get info from 4.18.16-300 as to what source files were compiled for this version of fedora?

https://fedora.pkgs.org/29/fedora-x86_64/ gives a list of rpm packages only.

https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/index didn't give me anything either.

Answer (score 0):

A really short [google search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=fedora+kernel+4.18.16-300) gave me [this site](https://fedora.pkgs.org/29/fedora-x86_64/kernel-4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html). There I read: `Source Package   kernel-4.18.16-300.fc29.src.rpm` - you can download the source for your rpm and even built it yourself. Each `rpm` usually has a source package.

For browsing kernel source however I would recommend using many of cool online sites, such as [elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source).

Comment: Source package isn't of much help to me. Say https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c I want to tinker with this file here, I would like to have this source available, I need to build it and deploy. That is where the problem lies.

Comment: ? Download source package, unpack source package, find the file, edit it, build the rpm from source, install rpm. Where do you have a problem?